# Ionic build fails with "Subprocess Error" only when using --prod flag

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, npm

Trying to build my ionic 4 app for production. It worked fine until now, suddenly a commit that only changed some html around made our builds fail.

Error msg:

```
  ionic Error
  ionic     at new SubprocessError (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myProjectPath/@ionic/utils-subprocess/dist/index.js:40:23)
  ionic     at ChildProcess.p.on (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myProjectPath/@ionic/utils-subprocess/dist/index.js:128:27)
  ionic     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
  ionic     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
  ionic     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5) +1m
```

ionic info

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.12.0 (/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/myProjectPath/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.6.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.9
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.3.9
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.9
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.5.1

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : not available
   Cordova Plugins       : not available

System:

   NodeJS : v10.16.0 (/usr/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.9.0
   OS     : Linux 3.10
```

Command that doesnt work:

```
ionic build --prod
```

Commands that do work and build fine:

```
ionic build
ionic build --aot --minifyjs --minifycss
```

npm update/npm doctor didn't resolve my problem. I heard that removing cordova helps sometimes, didn't work for me.
Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: can u show the html? maybe a missing closing tag or something

Comment: It's quite a long file and I checked it multiple times, it is correct. Also, wouldn't that produce an error while compiling without production? It did until now at least...

Comment: can you send all errors

Comment: What more errors do you mean? Thats all the errors I get, even if I run in --verbose mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as it stands, a simple restart fixed the error. I don't know how or why, but its gone